# File not found when running from slave node using local path

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform

I have created hadoop cluster in google cloud platform. It consists of 1 master and 3 slaves. When I tried run a hadoop job on master using local path it worked fine. But when I run the job from slave using local path it's giving me the following error:

```
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/hduser/sample.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocatedFileStatusFetcher.getFileStatuses(LocatedFileStatusFetcher.java:155).
```

The file is located in local of the slave machine. Without uploading the file to hdfs is there a way to run by specifying the local path in the slave.

Comment: Can you add some code snippet to show how you are trying to access the local files ? Did you try something like: Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Path pt = new Path("file://home/hduser/sample.txt");

Comment: from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext(appName = "test")
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
text_file = sc.textFile("file:///home/hduser/sample.txt")
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
counts.saveAsTextFile("gs://prthutest/data/out")

Comment: You run the job in master and have the file in slave. How does that make it a local file?

Comment: If am running the script from master terminal and the file is located in local path(master) then its working fine.Then i deleted the file from master and created a new file in slave.Now am running the job from slave terminal and the file is located in local path(slave) then its not working.
error is like ......: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/hduser/sample1.txt